# Booting Windows Embedded Compact 7 in virtual machine fails - Stop error 7B

Tags: boot, virtualbox, drivers, windows-embedded-7, windows-ce

The user interface of some specialized industrial equipment is implemented as an app running on Windows Embedded Compact 7. The OS has been installed on an obsolete industrial PC ([Aaeon GENE-9455 rev.a1.1](https://www.aaeon.com/en/p/3-and-half-inch-sbc-gene-9455-rev-a21) motherboard). Regrettably that motherboard is now deceased; The power delivery of one of the chips doesn't come up correctly and the boot sequence hangs.

The firm that deployed the PC isn't around anymore, and I lack access to the source. As I see it, there are four potential ways to fix this machine - they are all painful and not guaranteed to succeed.

1. Component-level board repair
2. Sourcing a new old stock or refurbished board from some forgotten warehouse somewhere
3. Porting the application to different hardware and software
4. Running the entire OS on a virtual machine, which is then easy to host on any hardware and software

---

I'm trying the virtualization route. I imaged the compact flash card, generated a virtual hard disk from it and threw it in VirtualBox 6.1.16. However, trying to start the virtual machine quickly ends in a BSoD of the guest system, with error code STOP: 0x0000007B (INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE).

The same issue is apparently common when migrating more mainstream Microsoft OS's such as Windows XP and 7 to virtual machines. While they may or may not be applicable to WEC7, I have tried the following suggested solutions. Nothing has changed.

- Telling windows to load all possibly relevant drivers on boot by editing the registry manually. I loaded the SYSTEM hive of the guest system (\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM) as SYSTEM_guest in the registry editor of the host system, navigated to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM_guest\ControlSet001\services\ and changed the "start" value of each key to "0" (meaning: start driver during earliest boot phase) for the following keys: aliide, amdide, atapi, cmdide, intelide, msahci, pciide, viaide
- Trying different virtual storage controller options such as IDE (PIIX3, PIIX4 and ICH6), SATA (AHCI), SCSI (LSI Logic and BusLogic)
- Automatic startup repair with windows 7 32 bit install disc ISO.
- Installing new drivers into the image using aforementioned windows install disc. More specifically, Intel ATAPI and AHCI for windows 7 32 bit.